# Different build result

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, devexpress

Even though I execute same msbuild batch file with same source code which is a solution of visual studio 2013, I get different files as result.

I'm using msbuild command batch file to make deploy files. One PC has installed DevExpress, and another PC hasn't, and those 2 PCs make different build files. PC without DevExpress includes extra dll files which are not even refered in solution. After I removed DevExpress, the results became same. But I don't understand why.

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Your solution might be referring to files which may be internally referring to the extra dll files.

Comment: Thanks, then is there a way to figure it out?